# Connect not working in class with qt creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator

Can anyone tell me a new question!
I create a new class and connect when the user right-clicks, it runs into the prepareMenu slot. But when I run it, it doesn't work.Normally,I put it in MainWindow and it runs ok.
Can anyone guide me how to fix it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMEgv.png)
Run Image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmC6r.png)

Can anyone guide me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```cpp
treeV3->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
connect(treeV3, &QTreeView::customContextMenuRequested, this, &TestConnect::prepareMenu);
```

> There are different policies and/or modes, one of them is "CustomContextMenu".